# All the stored procedures in SQL Server are stored in which database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Can you please tell me to know all the stored procedures in SQL Server are stored in which database? I have confusion between master DB or model DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stored procedures are stored in the database in which they are created. The stored procedures stored in master are the ones that are shipped with SQl Server, the master database is used by the SQL Server Engine.

The model database is a template for other databases. When you create a new database new a copy of the model database is created. So if you have tables or stored procedures you wish to have in all newly created databases you can add them to the model database.